# Do I need registration under the Greek Law for inflatable canoe having length between 1 to 2.80 meters?

Tags: boats, canoes

I thought to buy an inflatable canoe and cross the following distance between Poros Island and Daskaleio:

[image: Routes that I will follow]

But do inflatable canoe such as this [one](https://www.skroutz.gr/s/11947867/Waimea-Cherokee-88YB-MLW-%CE%A6%CE%BF%CF%85%CF%83%CE%BA%CF%89%CF%84%CF%8C-Kayak-%CE%98%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%AC%CF%83%CF%83%CE%B7%CF%82-2-%CE%91%CF%84%CF%8C%CE%BC%CF%89%CE%BD-%CE%A0%CE%BF%CE%BB%CF%8D%CF%87%CF%81%CF%89%CE%BC%CE%BF.html) (link for reference) need to be registered under the Greek law as a vessel;

Comment: Well both of those place names seem rather common.  But for those who are curious it appears to be [here](https://www.openstreetmap.org/query?lat=37.51667&lon=23.42998#map=17/37.51764/23.43398) (OpenStreetMap), meaning the straight lines are about 300m to 1km in length. I don;t know the sea conditions (and I know nothing about Greek boating regulations)

Comment: All documentation I can find in Greek maritime laws on registration refers to boats over 7m. I don't have a conclusive answer, however, but I have not seen any registration requirement for canoes or kayaks in any EU country I have sailed in.

Comment: @RoryAlsop in the UK there are licence requirements for such small craft on [some inland waterways](https://canalrivertrust.org.uk/enjoy-the-waterways/boating/licence-your-boat/short-term-visitor-licences) (widely ignored, and [included in membership of British canoeing](https://members.britishcanoeing.org.uk/waterways-licence/))

Comment: Thanks Chris - is it sad that I didn't even think of my own country...?

Comment: Inflatable boats seems that need no registration as long as under 7m and have no engine at all.

Comment: @RoryAlsop well, you did say EU :(